# Code Analyzer - removing a node fails without exception

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

As you may have guessed I'm learning all about roslyn, particularly as a code analyzer.

Syntax highlighting is working perfectly.  However the following - which is my code action - fails silently when removing the node:

```
    private async Task<Document> RemoveNode(Document document, LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax typeDecl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> oldNode = typeDecl.DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();

        SyntaxNode oldRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);

        SyntaxNode newRoot = oldRoot.RemoveNode(oldNode.Single(), SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia); //Analyzer fails here

        return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
    }
```

Subject:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FruitMix fm = new FruitMix(); //This is the matched node
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing the 'bigger' picture with how to work with Roslyn, so although help here would be amazing I'd also love some links / resources that'll help me.

I've uploaded this [project here](https://github.com/medmondson/IDisposableMarker) although not a 'minimial' example it will readily reproduce the problem.  The code above is in `CodeFixProvider.cs`.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you calling the code? Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I can go [one better](https://github.com/medmondson/IDisposableMarker).  I started out attempting to mark IDisposables but reduced the problem to simply attempting to remove a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code with break on all exceptions thrown enabled, I can see that it throws `ArgumentNullException` deep in the call stack inside `RemoveNode()`, specifically in `SyntaxFactory.LocalDeclarationStatement()`.

The exception is confusing (which is already [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4412)), but it is actually your error: you're trying to remove `VariableDeclarationSyntax` from its parent, which is `LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax` (the syntax for that would be something like *LocalDeclarationStatement* : `const`? *VariableDeclaration* `;`). And since `LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax` without `VariableDeclarationSyntax` is not valid, you get the exception.

The simplest fix is to just remove the parent `LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax`:

```
SyntaxNode newRoot = oldRoot.RemoveNode(oldNode.Single().Parent, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
```